# Not receiving data from server using Retrofit 2

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

I am trying to retrieve Reddit information from a particular subreddit using Retrofit 2. I have followed many tutorials and videos and my code seems to be correct from my perspective but I only manage to have null objects in my model class. I have the permission for internet in the Manifest.

This is a link the JSON I am working with [HERE](https://www.reddit.com/r/battlestations/hot/.json)

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    TextView mTextView;
    Data mData;
    private static final String TAG = "Battlestations";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test_view);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Call<Data> serviceCall = Service.getDesktopService().desks();
    serviceCall.enqueue(new Callback<Data>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Data> call, Response<Data> response)
        {

            Log.d("Reponce","return");
            Log.i(TAG, "Response is " + mData.getChildren());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Data> call, Throwable t)
        {

        }
    });
  }
}
```

Api/Service Class

```
public class Service
{
    private static final String BASE_URL = "https://www.reddit.com/r/";
    private static DeskInterface mRetrofit;


    public static DeskInterface getDesktopService()
    {
        if(mRetrofit == null)
        {
            Retrofit build = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();

            mRetrofit = build.create(DeskInterface.class);
        }
        return mRetrofit;
    }

    public interface DeskInterface
    {
        @GET("battlestations/hot/.json")
        Call<Data> desks();
    }

}
```

Data

```
public class Data
{
    private List<Child> children = null;

    public List<Child> getChildren()
    {
        return children;
    }

    public void setChildren(List<Child> children)
    {
        this.children = children;
    }
}
```

Child

```
public class Child
{
    private Data_ data;

    public Data_ getData()
    {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Data_ data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Data_

```
public class Data_
{
    private String subreddit;
    private Integer score;
    private String author;
    private String subredditNamePrefixed;
    private String url;
    private String title;

    public String getSubreddit()
    {
        return subreddit;
    }

    public void setSubreddit(String subreddit)
    {
        this.subreddit = subreddit;
    }

    public Integer getScore()
    {
        return score;
    }

    public void setScore(Integer score)
    {
        this.score = score;
    }

    public String getAuthor()
    {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author)
    {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public String getSubredditNamePrefixed()
    {
        return subredditNamePrefixed;
    }

    public void setSubredditNamePrefixed(String subredditNamePrefixed)
    {
        this.subredditNamePrefixed = subredditNamePrefixed;
    }

    public String getUrl()
    {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url)
    {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getTitle()
    {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title)
    {
        this.title = title;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `mData = response.body()` in `onResponse()`  (also check `response.isSuccessful()` first)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your Data does not correspond with Reddit JSON. Your **Data** class

```
public class Data {
    private List<Child> children = null;
}
```

does not match with the given json, which is:

```
{
  "kind":"listing",
  "data":{
    "modhash":"...",
    "children":[...],
    "after":"...",
    "before":"..."
   }
}
```

Retrofit automagically convert from json to java but only if the mapping is correct. 
A correct Java class would be:

```
public class Subreddit {
  String kind;
  Data data;
}

public class Data{
  String modhash;
  List<Child> children;
  String after;
  String before;
}
```

and then modify desks method interface to

```
Call<Subreddit> desks();
```

You would have to go recursively for the entire depth of the JSON to get the right mapping.
But before you get to work, just replace your Retrofit interface:

```
public interface DeskInterface{
    @GET("battlestations/hot/.json")
    Call<Data> desks();
}
```

with:

```
public interface DeskInterface{
   @GET("battlestations/hot/.json")
   Call<JsonObject> desks();
}
```

and it should return something. If is still null, then further investigation is needed. If it returns a valid response(some json text) then copy/paste that subreddit to [this website](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) where it converts all the json to a valid Java class